# How to prevent Main form from closing after handling exception error?

Tags: c#, winforms, exception

I have a multi form application. My mainform startup is called startFrm. In it I have a menu object which calls multiple (child/sub) forms. I am looking to add a global level exception handler through which if there is any unhandled exception in any of the child forms, I can catch it - show it in a proper manner; and then have the user continue with the main form, maybe do something else.

I have used the below in Program.cs before my main form gets called:

```
Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(new ThreadExceptionHandler().ApplicationThreadException);
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
```

Here is the ApplicationThreadException Handler code:

```
class ThreadExceptionHandler
    {
        internal void ApplicationThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            frmError frm = new frmError(e.Exception);
            frm.ShowDialog();
            return;
        }
    }
```

Now any unhandled exception gets caught by my error handler; but the application closes. How do I prevent this from happenning? I think it is fairly common scenario that a child form may have some unhandled exception; but the main form should continue to allow other functionality to be accessed.

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: The solution is to handle the exceptions properly. The unhandled exception handler is just for logging or saving data before terminating. See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.setunhandledexceptionmode?view=netcore-3.1) which states "UnhandledException cannot prevent an application from terminating."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the code gets to the global handler it has nowhere else to go. Technically, if you are not explicitly handling an exception somewhere, it's because you can't recover from it, otherwise you should catch exceptions before they reach the global handler. I would just use try / catch, wherever appropriate, in the main and child forms. In the child forms you would just close the form in the catch block. In the main form you decide when you can recover, otherwise throw.